# Vue detect when div is shown - load data to table when tab is shown, not when it's created

Tags: vue.js, tabs

In Vue I have tabs. The tabs looks like:

```
<ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
    <li v-for='(item, index) in userfilterresults'>
        <a data-toggle='tab' v-bind:href=\"'#tab-3' + index\" >{{ item.name }}</a>
    </li> 
</ul>
<div class='tab-content'>
    <div v-bind:id=\"'tab-3' + index\" class='tab-pane' v-for='(item, index) in userfilterresults' >
        <my-table :url='tasks/getall'></my-table>
```

The problem is that when I run application it load data for all tabs. But I want to load data only for tab that was clicked. In my-table component I have method load but I need to call it when user click in tab - li in this case.
Is any event in vue which allow detect when div tab-pane is shown? Because now data are loaded when div tab-pane is created.

Comment: You could hook up a click listener: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html another option is to isolate a single tab into a component and use the `created` or `mounted` lifecycle hook to let it load data.

Comment: please provide `script` part

Comment: Thanks, it works, I have href attribute and I added @click='mymethod' statement